# li Element Numbering in IE9 moving towards right bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Every time I refresh the page content, the numbering in the `li` elements moves towards the bottom-right in IE9 but works fine for other browsers (firefox and chrome). Does this require an IE specific fix or is it a mistake I've made?

*Javascript:*

```js
if (jQuery("#" + divName).html() == "") {
    document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = content;
}
```

*CSS:*

```css
ol.rounded {
    counter-reset: my-counter;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ol.rounded li {
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
ol.rounded li:before {
    border: 10px solid #69b13b;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    left: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    width: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
ol.rounded li:after {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    content: counter(my-counter, decimal);
    counter-increment: my-counter;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
}
```

*HTML:*

```html
<ol class="rounded">
    <li>
        <p>Abhishek Agarwal</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: why are using jQuery in the if condition but dont use it further on? replace `document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = content;` with `jQuery("#" + divName).html(content);`. Secondly, what is `counter-reset: my-counter`? its not valid css, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every refresh, css (already present for the page) was added again to the head. Because of multiple css applied li elements were moving.